# How to Exclude a Specific Node from a Block View

Tags: blocks, views

I know you can exclude the current node from a list view.

What I'm trying to do is exclude a specific node from a block view.

I have a list of the Top 5 Viewed pages I created into a block view, but I'm trying to hide one of them that keeps showing as it's the home page. I'd like to exclude that from the view.

Is it possible? I couldn't find anything in Contextual Filters.

I'm using Drupal 7 btw

Regards
Tony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter `Content:Nid` in the view and select `is not equal to` operator.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just add a filter on node id which excludes the node in question